# Access denied when inserting in collection anonymously

Tags: meteor

When i try to insert into collection without being authentication i get access denied error ,here are my permissions :

```
 signedforms.allow({
  'insert': function(userId, doc) {
    return userId;
  },
  'update': function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    return userId;
  },
  'remove': function(userId, doc) {
    return userId;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something without ' ' on methods and return true instead of id:

```
signedforms.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return true;
  }
```

For more info look at this post https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/

Comment: Keys can explicitly be written as strings when using the object literal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not authenticated then there's no `userId`, so your functions are returning `undefined`. Just return `true` instead.